# Django server running but can't hit url

Tags: python, django

I am on Windows 10. I have a Django server running which said the following:

```
python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

This is the DRF tutorial. When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/, I get the screen you get when your internet is down:

```
This site can’t be reached  127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

Every time I hit the URL, the server doesn't register anything. Usually a new line would print showing the request and either 200 or an error.
I have never seen this happen after running a Django server. I also don't usually do python on windows I prefer Linux. I'm assuming this is a Windows issue.

Comment: Have you checked the Windows firewall? I'm not sure why it would be blocking ports on localhost though. I don't use Windows often but the dev server usually works fine for me there.

Comment: maybe you should specify port.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use `python manage.py runserver` without specifying the port.
the only thing you have to do is just add port next to your command:

```
python manage.py runserver 8000
```

with following command you Django project will run on local server on port 8000 and you can access it with the below URL:

**`localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000`**

Comment: We can use `python manage.py runserver` without specifying the port because by default Django runs it on `127.0.0.1:8000`. Moreover when this command runs in terminal you can see where it ran.

Comment: For some reason it randomly started working guys. I really dont like python on windows

Comment: That's documented here, by the way: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver

Comment: @TomCarrick that's what i'm trying to say it runs by default at 127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: I know, I was just adding detail.

Comment: @codyc4321 You can not blame python on windows or django for it millions of user run it on windows and they don't have an error, I believe that error must've been on your side.

Comment: I have given a port of 8000 still it says 'site cannot be reached'

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by typing some random letters in a file, and trying to rerun the server. This time, it actually showed the error, a lack of importing 'include' in the url file. After fixing the error (that didn't show up the first 3 times I ran the server) the issue is fixed